# inverse in condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with ids and a list of ids(1,3,4,5,2,29,24). I can see what ids from that list are in table with such query:

```
select * from tbl1 where id in (1,3,4,5,2,29,24)
```

But is it possible to see the numbers from this list of ids, that are not exist in tbl1 without creating temporary table? Something like

```
select * from tbl1 where (1,3,4,5,2,29,24) not in id
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax error? select * from tabla where id not in (1,3,4,5,2,29,24)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table in the query:

```
select id
from (select 1 as id union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
      select 2 union all select 29 union all select 24
     ) id
where not exists (select 1 from tbl1 where tbl1.id = id.id);
```

If you want to see ids that are both in the table and not in the table, then use a `left join`:

```
select id.id, tbl1.*
from (select 1 as id union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
      select 2 union all select 29 union all select 24
     ) id left join
     tbl1
     on tbl1.id = id.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from tbl1 where id not in (1,3,4,5,2,29,24)

Comment: Sorry same answer at Fabio's comment

Comment: But it is not I need, it shows ids that are not in list while I need position in list, that are not among table ids.